Overwrite a file from a redirection to standard output
I don't understand why I can't overwrite fic1. I'm on Ubuntu 24.04
[14:48]-[elouan@elouan-KLVL-WXX9]-[~/SYS/exo3/test]- $ echo "test1" > fic1.txt

[14:49]-[elouan@elouan-KLVL-WXX9]-[~/SYS/exo3/test]- $ cat fic1.txt
test1

[14:49]-[elouan@elouan-KLVL-WXX9]-[~/SYS/exo3/test]- $ echo "test2" > fic1.txt
bash: fic1.txt : impossible d'écraser le fichier existant

[14:49]-[elouan@elouan-KLVL-WXX9]-[~/SYS/exo3/test]- $ cat fic1.txt
test1

[14:51]-[elouan@elouan-KLVL-WXX9]-[~/SYS/exo3/test]- $ ls -l fic1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 elouan elouan 6 sept. 13 14:49 fic1.txt

I tried in dash, it works fine, the file overwrites fine, but not in bash

You should include a translation for any foreign text. This error says "impossible to overwrite the existing file"

You might find an answer here: Prevent overwriting a file with redirection.

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] for tips, like starting with your own research. I found that question by googling "bash prevent overwriting file", guessing that there was an option to do that.

You have noclobber on (perhaps from .bashrc?). Unset it for the current shell with
set +o noclobber

